# How to I populate .mat database in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How do I train images and make a .mat file?
I am trying the following simple matlab program :

http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22030-image-retrieval-query-by-example-demo

Documentation
https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~nnikvand/Coderep/imQuery/documentation.html

Now, this zip package already includes a .mat file which has histograms of all the sample images provided for querying.I want to query over my own sample-set of images.

I figured out that I need that getimagehist function to calculate the histogram and populate a database of my images in .mat format. but how exactly do i do it? I am a newbie in matlab that's why i have no idea. A little guidance/help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, the .mat format is used for saving Matlab workspaces. You can create .mat files with

```
save(filename,variables)
```

It is documented here: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

If you need help in creating the histograms from images, check `imhist`: http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html

As an example of saving a histogram in .mat file

```
myHistogram = imhist(image);
save('myMatFile', 'myHistogram');
```